# Trying to Understand CFTree Documentation

Tags: ios, objective-c, data-structures, core-foundation

I am trying to make a CFTree that holds strings as nodes. I am having trouble understanding the documentation for the class. Here is the link: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/corefoundation/Reference/CFTreeRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFTreeSetContext

When you create a CFTree you call CFTreeCreate and pass in an allocator and a context. The allocator parameter I understand, but I don't understand the context argument.

Here are the fields you need to fill in in a context before you pass the context to CFTreeCreate:

`version` - this one I understand, I just make it version 0

`info` - Will I just set this to the NSString? Isn't that not OK because I need to use the __bridge or something? I'm kind of confused about this one

`retain` - Does ARC take care of retaining even though this is a Core Foundation class? I'm not sure what to put here

`release` - same as above

`copyDescription` - Not sure what the point of this field is or if I need it for what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Will I just set this to the NSString? Isn't that not OK because I need to use the __bridge or something?

If you want to do that, you'll have to do a non retaining bridging cast.  Because `NSString` is toll free bridged with `CFStringRef`, in the tree, you can treat your `NString` as a `CFStringRef` and set the retain and release functions to `CFRetain` and `CFRelease` respectively - I think it should be OK, the prototypes look compatible.

> Does ARC take care of retaining even though this is a Core Foundation class?

No, it doesn't, but if you set the retain and release functions as I suggested, you should be OK.

> copyDescription - Not sure what the point of this field is or if I need it for what I'm trying to do

It just spits out a description, in the same way as `-description` does for a Cocoa object.  You can leave it null, but if your info is an `NSString` something like this will do the trick:

```
CFStringRef* copyDescription(void* info)
{
    return CFStringCreateCopy(someAllocator, (CFStringRef) info);
}
```

I haven't tried it, so it might not work.

Comment: Thanks that's super helpful. Is a nonretaining bridge cast just _bridge or _bridge retained?

Comment: @user3139679 __bridge

Comment: Thanks! But why? Don't I need to perform retain operations on whatever I assign to the info field? Or even with the normal bridge cast the retain and release fields of the struct will take care of that?

Comment: @user3139679  No.  The CFTree manages the retains and releases using the functions you provide (CFRetain and CFRelease).  Although, thinking about it you might need to do the first one, in which case use __bridge retained

Comment: Why would I need to do the first one? Because it might stop persisting before the first call to CFRetain?

Comment: Yes possibly.  Try it and see.  If you do need to do the first retain, your code will crash if you just use __bridge.